# JQuery UI inheritance polymorphism

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, inheritance, widget, polymorphism

Is there a way to have polymorphism in the inheritance of a widget in jQuery UI?

For example I want to do something like:

```
$.widget('tr.fatherClass', {
  getValue: function() {
    return null;
  }
  ...
});
// sonClass1: extends from the father
$.widget('tr.sonClass1', $.tr.fatherClass, {
  getValue: function() {
    return this._fooFunction1();
  }
  ...
});
// sonClass2: extends from the father
$.widget('tr.sonClass2', $.tr.fatherClass, {
  getValue: function() {
    return this._fooFunction2();//
  }
  ...
});
// create an instance of a "sonClass"
$('#foo1').sonClass1(options);  
$('#foo2').sonClass2(options);
```

Then I want to use the method "getValue" without knowing the name of the son class:

```
$('#foo1').fatherClass('getValue'); // run _fooFunction1() of sonClass1
$('#foo2').fatherClass('getValue'); // run _fooFunction2() of sonClass2
```

But this is not possible:

```
jquery.js:250 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on variable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'getValue'
```

In the forum of JQuery, Scott Gonzalez explains that "*Creating a widget only creates one widget, not every widget in the prototype chain*" [link](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/widget-inheritance-no-polymorphism)

There is any workaround or solution to do this in an elegant way?

Comment: This is not how jQuery plugins work. You have to handle your logic in same plugin. What real world advantage do you gain from this?

Comment: I can create an interface and control different kinds of widget with the same interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save `fatherClass` as a `data` for element with some key like `fatherObject` it should go in father's `_create()` method...

```
$.widget('tr.fatherClass', {
  _create: function(){
    $(this.element).data( 'fatherObject', $.tr.fatherClass.prototype );
  },
  ...
};
```

And later retrieve values using...

```
$('#foo').data('fatherObject').getValue()
```

or

```
$('#bar').data('fatherObject').getValue()
```

```js
$.widget('tr.fatherClass', {
  _create: function(){
    $(this.element).data( 'fatherObject', $.tr.fatherClass.prototype );
  },
  getValue: function() {
    return 'yellow'; // Father likes yellow
  }
});

// extends from the father
$.widget('tr.sonClass', $.tr.fatherClass, {
  getValue: function() {
    return 'blue'; // Son likes blue
  }
});

// extends from the father
$.widget('tr.daughterClass', $.tr.fatherClass, {
  getValue: function() {
    return 'pink'; // Daughter likes pink
  }
});

// This is son
$('#foo').sonClass();

// This is daughter
$('#bar').daughterClass();

// Son's fav color
console.log( $('#foo').sonClass('getValue') );

// Son's FATHER's fav color
console.log( $('#bar').data('fatherObject').getValue() );

// Daughter's fav color
console.log( $('#bar').daughterClass('getValue') );

// Daughter's FATHER's fav color
console.log( $('#bar').data('fatherObject').getValue() );
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id='foo'></div>
<div id='bar'></div>
```

Comment: I did some changes in your answer, but the main idea is exactly what I want

Answer (score 3):

In OOD is important to favor composition over inheritance. But if you still want polymorphism, instead of switching plugins you can create a function as a plugin variable you can overwrite in your application logic

Example:

```
$.widget('myWidget', {
    getValue: function() {
      if(userfunc != null)
         return userfunc();
      return null;
   }
   userfunc: null
  });
```

and then you can create different versions for userfunc

```
userfunc1 = function(){  return 43; }
userfunc2 = function(){  return 38; }

$('#foo').myWidget({userfunc : userfunc1})
value = $('#foo').myWidget('getValue') <= returns 47

$('#foo').myWidget({userfunc : userfunc2})
value = $('#foo').myWidget('getValue') <= returns 38
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, but is a good start point, I going to think about it

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access over written parent's methods from outside the widget declaration, but if you have written `sonClass` yourself, you can call same method from parent by using `this._super()`, implementation in your `sonClass` will look something like this...

```
// extends from the father
$.widget('tr.sonClass', $.tr.fatherClass, {
  getValue: function( fromFather ) {
    if ( 'father' == fromFather ) { // If 'father' is passed as argument
      return this._super(); // Get the result from father's method
    } else {
      return this._$input.val();
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

You can call method from father like this...

```
console.log( $('#foo').sonClass('getValue', 'father') );
```

For reference
http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_super

### UPDATE

We add new `fathersMethod` method to father which returns results from father...

```
$.widget('tr.fatherClass', {
  //Add this to father to get properties from father
  fathersMethod: function(prop) {
    if ( typeof $.tr.fatherClass.prototype[prop] == 'function' )
    return $.tr.fatherClass.prototype[prop]();
  },
  getValue: function() {
    return 'yellow'; // Father likes yellow
  },
  ...
  ...
  ...
});
```

Now for any son (or daughter) who inherits from father... can call father's methods like this...

```
$('#foo').sonClass('fathersMethod', 'getValue');
```

Here's an updated snippet ;-)

```js
$.widget('tr.fatherClass', {
  fathersMethod: function(prop) {
    if ( typeof $.tr.fatherClass.prototype[prop] == 'function' )
    return $.tr.fatherClass.prototype[prop]();
  },
  getValue: function() {
    return 'yellow'; // Father likes yellow
  }
});

// extends from the father
$.widget('tr.sonClass', $.tr.fatherClass, {
  getValue: function() {
    return 'blue'; // Son likes blue
  }
});

// extends from the father
$.widget('tr.daughterClass', $.tr.fatherClass, {
  getValue: function() {
    return 'pink'; // Daughter likes pink
  }
});

// This is son
$('#foo').sonClass();

// This is daughter
$('#bar').daughterClass();

// Son's fav color
console.log( $('#foo').sonClass('getValue') );

// Son's FATHER's fav color
console.log( $('#foo').sonClass('fathersMethod', 'getValue') );

// Daughter's fav color
console.log( $('#bar').daughterClass('getValue') );

// Daughter's FATHER's fav color
console.log( $('#bar').daughterClass('fathersMethod', 'getValue') );
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id='foo'></div>
<div id='bar'></div>
```

Comment: I have clarified a little my question. I have no problem to run code of the father in the son. My problem is that I have many kinds of son and I want to control them in a similar way.

Comment: Updated my answer, the idea is to create a new method in father which accepts prop parameter, checks if `prop` is a method in `$.tr.fatherClass`s prototype, if yes calls it returns the value.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, because you have to know that #bar is a daughterClass and #foo is a sonClass. My point is to forget that and invoke them using a interface, like I show in my question. $('#foo').fatherClass('getValue'); $('#bar').fatherClass('getValue'); <--- in this example I don't care if there are sonClass, daughterClass or fatherClass

Comment: Added a new answer to address the issue... ( didn't wanna update the answer again ;P )

Answer (score 2):

Normally what you're calling here polymorphism is standard inheritance and instantiation behaviour.

```
$('#foo1').sonClass1(options);  
$('#foo2').sonClass2(options);
```

creates two distinct class instances.

`foo1.getValue` will execute the instantiated classes, here *sonClass1*, `getValue` defintion (code block) which is fooFunction1.

`foo2.getValue` will execute the instantiatedclass's, here *sonClass2*, `getValue` definition (code block) which is fooFunction2.

The later calls here

```
$('#foo1').fatherClass('getValue'); // run _fooFunction1() of sonClass1
$('#foo2').fatherClass('getValue'); // run _fooFunction2() of sonClass2
```

are calls not to the *sonClass1* or *sonClass2* `getValue` method defintions but that of the *fatherClass*.

You would normally expect in both the above cases for the father's `getValue` method defintion to be used.

Your error however says it's undefined.

I don't use JQuery but I would suspect it's inheritance mechanism does not instantiate the parent class.

All of us who have been using js have encountered this issue and have resolved it in a variety of ways.